# How to make an active button using routing?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the `Menu` component. And I need to make it so that if some link from the menu is active, then the button should also become active, that is, painted in some color. How to do it?

```html
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" routerLinkActive="active">
        Directories
        <mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/directory/teams"
            routerLinkActive="color">Teams</button>
        <button mat-menu-item routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/directory/Teams"
            routerLinkActive="color">Masters</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a route is active with the router function `isActive` and declare `exactMatch: false`. Then you will get a boolean which says if the exact route 'directory' or a sub is activated. Because your `mat-button` is not a router link you can't use the `routerLinkActive` attribute. Instead define the CSS-class with `ngClass`.

HTML:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [ngClass]={'active': isDirectoryPath()}>
    Directories
    <mat-icon>expand_more</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/directory/teams"
        routerLinkActive="color">Teams</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/directory/Teams"
        routerLinkActive="color">Masters</button>
</mat-menu>
```

TS:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

isDirectoryPath() {
  return this.router.isActive('directory', false); // <-- boolean is for exactMatch
}
```